# so..how do people program with visual c(++)?

Tags: php, c++, c, visual-c++

I am a php programmer. I am going to study visual c++ for windows programming.

since 4 years ago, I never built a web page without a framework. Do visual c++ programmers use a framework as well?

Comment: MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) was a pretty popular framework when I used it. Probably still actively used by many developers.

Comment: Are you serious about this question? What kind of application are you building? What kind of framework do you need? What are your specific needs? What is your scenario? You ask `Do visual c++ programmers use a framework as well` and the answer is `yes, some of them do`.

Comment: and even if it were a full question, it should go on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @marcog // I never knew there is such website. Thanks.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov //
I am serious about this question. 
I am trying to learn, not trying to build something
I don't know what kind of frameworks out there for C++

Comment: @Moon, your question is too broad. There are different frameworks for achieving different kind of tasks. What kind of task are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Moon Ask your question on p.se.com (related to SO), you'll get a better response there. SO typically requires a question to involve code. When you do post though, put in a little effort explaining what you're asking. In its current state, it's unanswerable.

Comment: @marcog, in its current state the question is answerable and the answer is `yes`, but I highly doubt that the OP was looking for this answer :-) If he didn't he needs to provide more details about his scenario and about what kind of problems he is trying to solve: is he trying to build a web site, a client application, a device driver, an application which controls the Mars Rover on Mars, ...

Answer (score 6):

> Do visual c++ programmers use a framework as well?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

> Do visual c++ programmers use a
>   framework as well?

Some do, some don't.